# Laravel Wireui DatePicker not defined

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-livewire

I built a form in laravel, livewire and wireui for the components.
When I go to insert the datetime picker it doesn't work and I get the following error:

wireui_datetime_picker not defined.

my code is:

```
<x-datetime-picker
    label="Appointment Date"
    placeholder="Appointment Date"
    wire:model.defer="normalPicker"
/>
```

why? Any ideas?
Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 1):

include @wireUiScripts before Alpine.js

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You must include `@wireUiScripts` before `@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])`

Answer (score -2):

You must import the trait into the livewire component.

use WireUi\Traits\Actions;
use Actions;